# node.js ./configure warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to install node.js and I get this list of warnings when I run ./configer. I don't know which libraries/packages I miss on my Debian installation (Linux 2.6.32.6 ppc GNU/Linux on a Bubba2 sever)

```
Checking for gnutls >= 2.5.0             : fail 

--- libeio --- 
Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : fail 
Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : fail 
--- libev ---
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : not found 
Checking for header port.h               : not found 
Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found 
Checking for function kqueue             : not found 
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : not found
```

Can you tell me what I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy gnutls dependency you will need libgnutls-dev. Both libeio and libev depend on C library only (AFAIK) so you will need libc6-dev package for that (which should be pulled in by libgnutls-dev I believe). Hope that helps.